# Resample error: ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    timestamp
2020-03-01 01:11:42.520      -674.0
2020-03-01 02:00:48.778      -700.0
2020-03-01 02:00:58.850      -702.0
2020-03-01 11:45:23.741     -1249.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51.021     -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51.021      -917.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51.021      -837.0
```

What I try to do is the following:

```
cum = (orders[['cum']]
        .resample('1S')
        .bfill()
        .fillna('ffill')
      )
```

But then I have the title error message, any idea what it means? Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are duplicates in the timestamp column.  Try creating a traditional index column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is filter first duplicated index values for resample like your solution and then filter dulicated to `added` Series, change index by floor and add to original with sorting:

```
print (orders)
                            cum
timestamp                      
2020-03-01 01:11:42.520  -674.0
2020-03-01 02:00:48.778  -700.0
2020-03-01 02:00:58.850  -702.0
2020-03-01 11:45:23.741 -1249.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51.021 -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51.021  -917.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51.021  -837.0
2020-03-02 01:56:54.021   -67.0

mask = orders.index.duplicated()
cum = (orders.loc[~mask, 'cum']
        .resample('1S')
        .bfill()
        .ffill()
      )
added = orders.loc[mask, 'cum']
added.index = added.index.floor('S')
cum = added.append(cum).sort_index()
print (cum.tail(10))
timestamp
2020-03-02 01:56:47   -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:48   -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:49   -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:50   -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51   -1229.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51    -917.0
2020-03-02 01:56:51    -837.0
2020-03-02 01:56:52     -67.0
2020-03-02 01:56:53     -67.0
2020-03-02 01:56:54     -67.0
Name: cum, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Viktor.w - tested and need change `mask = orders.index.duplicated()` to `mask = orders.index.duplicated(keep='last')`